# If is single in header.php

Tags: headers, single

I wanna do a query in my header.php inside "head" to generate a title. I wanna ask, if the current page is single an do it like it follows:

```
<?php if ( is_single() ) { ?>
<title>Test</title>
<?php } ?>
```

But it doesnt function an doesnt give out anything. Do I have to do another quaery over the "head tag" ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wp_head` action hook for it.

```
add_action('wp_head','hook_title');

function hook_title() {

    $output="<title>Test</title>";

    echo $output;

}
```

Comment: No sorry not possible because I have to do only in single and further the has to be some code added in header...

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code

```
if(is_single()){
   add_filter('the_title',function(){
     return 'test';
 });
}
```

and in your code you did not print out anything, so test you code also here

```
<?php if ( is_single() ) { 
   echo '<title>Test</title>';
 } ?>
```